# How to allow a range of ports in Kubernetes in containerPort variable?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In docker, I can expose a range of ports using "-p 65000-65050:65000-65050". How do I achieve this for kubernetes in a pod.yml or replication-controller.yml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. From the v1 API specs:

```
      "ports": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "hostPort": 0,
          "containerPort": 0,
          "protocol": "string",
          "hostIP": "string"
        }
      ]
```

Each port is uniquely identified and exposing host ports would be an anti-pattern in Kubernetes.

Comment: Binding to hostPort limits the number of places where a pod can be schedule. You can expose the your pod through a service project. See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/68cb50e7e4a492376810d26427b09ef12a343398/docs/user-guide/connecting-applications.md for an example.