# How to specify host port range instead of host port in kubernete's pod yaml file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, port, kubernetes-pod

In docker run command, we can specify host port range to bind to EXPOSEd container port. Same thing I want to do through Kubernetes. Does any one know, how to do that? My current pod definition is as-

```
apiVersion: v1  
kind: Pod  
metadata:  
  name: nginx-testing  
spec:  
   containers:  
   - name: nginx-container  
     image: docker.io/nginx  
     ports:  
     - containerPort: 80  
       hostPort: 9088
```

At the last line, Instead of specifying single port number, I want a range of port numbers.  I tried  something like `hostPort: 9088-9999 or 9088..9999`, but it wouldn't worked.

Comment: This should it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409684/how-to-allow-a-range-of-ports-in-kubernetes-in-containerport-variable

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Thanks.. It means we wont be able to specify range ports in kubernetes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Port ranges are not currently supported in any of the Kubernetes API objects. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23864) discussing port ranges in services. Please add your use case and your thoughts!